# Collection getting cleared when clearing the Source collection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, collections

I have a collection, "entity.DestinationDetailscollection". I then copied this collection to an another collection, "DestinationCollection" as shown in the below code. But whenever i clear the source collection(i.e entity.DestinationDetailscollection), the collection "DestinationCollection " is also getting cleared. Please help.

```
Dim DestinationCollection As New Collection(Of StudentDTO)

DestinationCollection = New Collection(Of StudentDTO)(entity.DestinationDetailscollection)

entity.DestinationDetailscollection.Clear()
```

Comment: It is a strange class with a name that is too attractive.  You should favor List(Of StudentDTO).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation of Collection(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll find that `Collection(Of T)` constructor does NOT copy the source collection supplied as the parameter. It just acts as a wrapper. So clearing one will clear the other.

This behavior is different from `List(Of T)` constructor, which actually copies the source collection elements (just object references are copied) into the new List object and thus creates a separate list.

Though you could always copy the entire list manually to the new collection object (a simple loop), you should prefere `List(Of T)` over `Collection(Of T)`.

As a side note, you're instantiating your `Collection` twice. You should dod it in one line:

```
Dim DestinationCollection As New Collection(Of StudentDTO)(entity.DestinationDetailscollection)
```

You should replace your first two lines with this one line.

Comment: ok thanks.... i have used loop to copy the collection to another collection and it worked.